# Prevent to redirect to 3rd party page after session destroy with javascript

Tags: javascript, session, browser-history

we have payment service provided by 3rd party and after payment is done, we are redirected to our order summary page. The problem is when someone hits back button actually he is redirected back to payments page. But we would like to prevent this and redirect somewhere to our side.

Is there any way to somehow block 3rd party page, after session is destroyed?

Eg.

```
session.onDestroy(){
   //add page to blacklist or something like this
}
```

or maybe delete this page from browsers history.

Thanks,

Comment: You say that when the payment is done and user clicks the back button is redirected to the payment page, is the payment page yours or 3rd party?

Comment: payment page is 3rd party.

Comment: Then I don't think there's much you can do, aside from asking the 3rd party to handle your payment in a single page, so that when the user clicks the back button will be sent back to a page of your control, then you could do something.

Comment: :(((( i thought so. Gosh